# Variable not declared in scope- getter/setters

Tags: c++

trying to implement simple getter and setter functions but compiler says that my variables are not defined in the scope when i run the getters/setters.
 So i added Course::getID() cause maybe the reason why i couldn't access them was because they were set as private. But then it said that the prototype did not match. So then i went to the header file and changed the prototype similar to CPP file. It then gave me the error: extra qualification 'Course::' on member getID(); any advise?

HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

const unsigned CourseNameSize = 10;

class Course {
public:
  Course();
  Course( const char * nam, char ID, unsigned cred );

  char getName() const;
  char getID() const;
  unsigned GetCredits() const;


  void setName( char name );
  void SetCredits( unsigned cred );
  void setID( char ID );

  friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream & os, const Course & C );
  friend std::istream & operator >>( std::istream & input, Course & C );

private:
  char name[CourseNameSize];
  char ID;
  int  credits;
};



inline unsigned Course::GetCredits() const
{
  return credits;
}

inline void Course::SetCredits( unsigned cred )
{
  credits = cred;
}
```

CPP FILE

```
#include "course.h"
using namespace std;

 Course::Course()
 {
   name[0] = '\0'; // it is a char * string, not a C++ string object.
 }

 Course::Course( const char * nam, char ID,
            unsigned cred )
 {
   strncpy( name, nam, CourseNameSize );
   ID = ID;
  credits = cred;
 }

 istream & operator >>( istream & input, Course & C )
 {
   input >> C.name >> C.ID >> C.credits;
   return input;
 }

 ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const Course & C )
 {
   os << "  Course:  " << C.name << '\n'
   << "  ID: " << C.ID << '\n'
   << "  Credits: " << C.credits << '\n';
  return os;
 }

 void setID(char ID) {ID =ID;}

 char getID() {return ID;}

 void setName(char name) {name = name;}

 char getName() {return name;}

 void setCredits(int credits) {credits = credits;}

 int getCredits() { return credits;}
```

Comment: `ID = ID;` surely you're running into problems. Use `this->ID` to disambiguate.

Comment: As an aside: there's no point in having data members be `private` if you provide getters and setters. For a type with no behaviour, like `Course` is currently, just make the data `public`.

Answer (score 4):

This is getting your program messed up:

```
ID = ID;
name = name;
credits = credits;
```

You probably should write

```
this->ID = ID;
this->name = name;
this->credits = credits;
```

And in your cpp file, since functions like `getID()` are class members, the correct way to define them is:

```
void Course::setID(char ID) { this_>ID = ID; }
char Course::getID() const { return this->ID; }
//                   ^^^^^
```

Don't miss the `const` specifier in function definition. That makes functions different.

---

Since you're using the classes `std::istream` and `std::ostream` (and their methods), you need to include the relevant headers in your cpp file:

**course.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "course.h"
using namespace std;
```

Comment: char Course::getID() **const**

Comment: @ricky You shouldn't prepend `Course::` **inside the class**, but you should **outside the class**.

Comment: thanks ibug, i will def remember to use this-> next time! appreciate all the help guys